# Create a macro variable from a data set

Tags: sas, macros

I was hoping you could help me with a task in SAS. I have a data set (2 by 2 of numbers) and I would like to extract each entry and store them individually as a macro variable for later use. I am not very familiar with macros so I am not sure if this is possible.

Many thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you included your data in the question.

I have used some random values in this example:

```
* create some sample data;
data testdata;
    input a b;
    datalines;
2.1 3.2
4.6 7.0
;
run;

* use CALL SYMPUT in a DATA step to assign the values to macro variables;
data _null_;
    set testdata;
    call symputx(catx('_','variable_a',_n_), a);
    call symputx(catx('_','variable_b',_n_), b);
run;

* view the macro variables values;
%put &=variable_a_1;
%put &=variable_a_2;
%put &=variable_b_1;
%put &=variable_b_2;
```

`call symputx()` is the relevant statement here. It's first argument is the name of the macro variable you want to assign a value to. The second argument is the value you want to assign to that variable.

I used the automatic variable `_n_` to avoid duplicating variable names. And the use of the `left()` functions here avoid spaces in the variable name and value.

Comment: No need to use the ancient CALL SYMPUT() function instead of the normal CALL SYMPUTX() function in this case because there is no need to store either leading or trailing spaces into the macro variable.

Comment: Thanks @Tom. I have edit the answer to include your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SYMPUTX` routine in a DATA Step.

Example:

```
data have;
  input p q @@;
  datalines;
1 2 3 4
;


data _null_;
  set have;
  array cols p q;
  do index = 1 to dim(cols);
    symbol_name = catx('_','A',_n_,index);
    putlog 'NOTE: ' symbol_name=;
    call symputx(symbol_name, cols(index));
  end;
run;

options nosource;

%put NOTE: &=A_1_1;
%put NOTE: &=A_1_2;
%put NOTE: &=A_2_1;
%put NOTE: &=A_2_2;

options source;
```

will produce the log entries such as the following

```
NOTE: symbol_name=A_1_1
NOTE: symbol_name=A_1_2
NOTE: symbol_name=A_2_1
NOTE: symbol_name=A_2_2
NOTE: There were 2 observations read from the data set WORK.HAVE.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


104
105  options nosource;
NOTE: A_1_1=1
NOTE: A_1_2=2
NOTE: A_2_1=3
NOTE: A_2_2=4
```